# Using netcat to connect to znc

Tags: netcat

I'm trying to send status updates to my IRC channel on irc.foo.com
My limitations are..

- The msg has to be sent to irc.foo.com from my ZNC account on znc.bar.com (znc is connected to irc.foo.com)
- The msg contents is sent by POST or GET request to znc.bar.com before being sent to IRC (If you don't get it keep reading)

I am root on znc.bar.com and I am connecting to port 6667 without ssl (unless I can get ncat working)
My plan is to send a POST request to a php file that will run my netcat command, however. I can't get netcat to login as me, or give me any output..

> root@HomeServer ~ $ netcat -vv znc.bar.com 6667
>   Connection to znc.bar.com 6667 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

After that I get no more output (I did try sending commands without the output).. any ideas? I'm up for suggestions.

Sorry for any bad english :P

Comment: Which commands are you sending?

Comment: /quote PASS uname:passwd and a whois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/chapter4.html
I needed to register the connection.